# Alias for Files in the Classpath Java

Tags: java

Is there anyway to pass the files in java classpath with aliases?

For example:

`java -cp ./file_type1.txt#file.txt com.example.JavaProgram`

This way the program would refer the file_type1.txt as file.txt in classpath. So, I can programatically pass multiple similar files with same reference and need not change anything in the java program.

Comment: why don't you pass the file name / path as a program argument instead?

Comment: I am using the file in the java program. So if use the file as ````file_type1.txt```` then I won't be able to pass other of my files. So I kept it generic one and thought this would be possible to alias the file in classpath.

Comment: I don't have it. If you start your program like that `java com.example.JavaProgram ./file_type1.txt` the in your main you can do `myFile = new File(args[0]);`. The you just need to pass this as a parameter of your method or put it in a `public static variable` and it will be available everywhere and flexible.

Comment: This way I won't be able to execute my program in distributed environment. I will have to keep the files in a shared directory where the files are accessible from every machine. But that NAS creation is not in my scope. That's why I was looking this kind of approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such way in JAVA (neither in any other language I think...).

BTW, in JAVA once the file has been added in the classpath, you can retrieve its content only with its name (w/o the path) `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourcesAsStream("file_type1.txt")`. No matter where it is.

Then you have 2 options:

- parse the classpath (`System.getProperty("java.class.path")` + File.pathSeparator to split the entries) of your application to detect the filename specified on the command line (probably the only txt file in the path)
- pass the name (only the name) of the file as a parameter of your application: java -cp ./file_type1.txt com.example.JavaProgram file_type1.txt

You then need to parse it and identify the name of the additional `.txt` file name you

Somehow you will have to introduce some dynamic behaviour in your application as you cannot create aliases.

HIH.

Comment: Thanks ZNK for confirming that. Even I was thinking along the same lines. Was just thinking it would be a nice feature for JVM. Don't know how much would be the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you create symbolic links (`ln -s`) on UNIX platforms outside of Java instead.

Comment: This way I would have to create the symlink everytime I need to execute for the file. That would like a crude way of doing it. Isn't there any provisioning of aliasing?